# Ranger in favored terrain with Camouflage

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ranger

Baring the more powerful forms of senses such as tremorsense and above, this question is concerned about normal vision, lowlight vision, darkvision, and scent. Magical tracking such as locate creature and divination spells are also not a concern for this question.

When a ranger is in their [favored terrain](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Core-Classes/Ranger/#TOC-Favored-Terrain-Ex-) they are able to leave no trail and can't be tracked. Then at 12th level they get [camouflage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/Core-Classes/Ranger/#TOC-Camouflage-Ex-) which lets them hide in said terrain even when there is no cover. I have something which prevents scent just in case the *'can't be tracked'* doesn't include a creature smelling me when we are close to each other. I also have a good stealth check.

So baring something literally tripping over my ranger while they are sleeping, would they be at risk in normal environments from the listed senses? To my understanding, something would have to be in my camp and then pass a perception check against my stealth check.

Comment: Is there a specific issue you're trying to address with this question? Just how difficult it is for a Ranger to set up a solo camp?

Comment: @Ifusaso Yes. Mostly its for my backstory as the ranger just likes wandering around.

Answer (score 1):

### This is technically ambiguous

There is no RAW way to hide in a camp site [without magic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hide-campsite/)/sleeping location. Stealth is explicitly used for movement

> **Action**
>
> Usually none. Normally, you make a Stealth check as part of movement, so it doesn’t take a separate action. However, using Stealth immediately after a ranged attack (see Sniping, above) is a move action.

[Survival](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/survival) is likewise unhelpful.

> You are skilled at surviving in the wild and at navigating in the wilderness. You also excel at following trails and tracks left by others.
> **Avoid Getting Lost/Avoid Natural Hazards**
> **Follow Tracks**
> **Survive in the Wilderness**
>
> - Get along in the wild. Move up to half your overland speed while hunting and foraging (no food or water supplies needed). You can provide food and water for one other person for every 2 points by which your check result exceeds 10.
> - Gain a +2 bonus on all Fortitude saves against severe weather while moving up to half your overland speed, or gain a +4 bonus if you remain stationary. You may grant the same bonus to one other character for every 1 point by which your Survival check result exceeds 15.
> - Keep from getting lost or avoid natural hazards, such as quicksand.
> - Predict the weather up to 24 hours in advance. For every 5 points by which your Survival check result exceeds 15, you can predict the weather for one additional day in advance.

Ambiguity is added in that stealth seems to end specifically when you could no longer use stealth (being observed or out of cover/concealment at the end of a turn) or when you attack. If this is interpreted somewhat liberally (making the assumption that anything that can be done in rounds can be done out of rounds, even when you're unable to "take actions" because you're [Helpless](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Conditions&Category=Combat)) then it could be assumed that using stealth to hide overnight is viable. Consult with your GM if you need to apply your Stealth check with -5 Dexterity mod instead of your own due to Helpless.

In fact, I think allowing it makes the most sense because...

### The ability is a really good justification to allow it

The combination of the Ranger's flavor, use of the term Camouflage for the ability, and logical sense of generally using Stealth to "find a place" to hide even when not actively hiding really suggest that it should work.

Expect table variance.

Comment: Stealth is not just for when moving, why would you think that? What, I cant stay still in a corner if someone enters a room, I have to be moving? Also, Im not so much hiding in a camp site as hiding the campsite itself. Which is the whole point of camouflage  netting https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/goods-and-services/hunting-camping-survival-gear/#TOC-Net When you hide under the netting in the appropriate terrain, you gain a +4 circumstance bonus on Stealth checks as long as you remain immobile and prone.

Comment: @Fering The text I linked from the rules is why I think that. I agree that you don't have to be *actively* Moving (as the Action), but it doesn't really provide rules to then remain hidden (although, now that I look at it again, it *kind of* does... I'll update my answer). The item linked provides an exception to the rules (as I suggest the Ranger ability should).